# Как вывести отправленные данные через AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма

```
<form>
 <input class="id">
 <input class="name">
 <button class="submit>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

данные отправляются в обработчик на php через ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){                                    
$('button.otverstiesubmit').on('click', function(e){                                                               
e.preventDefault() // без перезагрузки страницы

var id = $('input.id').val();
var name = $('input.name').val();

$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "add-user.php",
data: { id: id, name: name },

success: function() {
...
}
```

как вывести отправленные данные в новом div?

```
<div id="user">
<p>id</p>
<p>name</p>
</div>
```

Comment: отправленные или всё же полученные? в какое конкретно место дива надо что-то вывести?

Comment: Я отправляю данные из формы в файл обработчик add-user.php по клику на button без перезагрузки страницы. Данные добавляются в БД, тут всё ок. Сразу после этого мне нужно создать новый <div id="user">, как я описал выше и на место id и name подставить значения, которые я отправил в БД

Comment: Нужно прописать код в success: function() {...}, который будет создавать новый div и выводить данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае в колбэке надо написать:

```js
let id = 111;
let name = 'Ivan';

let html = `
<div id="user">
    <p>${id}</p>
    <p>${name}</p>
</div>
`;

$("body").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы при выводилось несколько div? допустим, я несколько раз отправил форму и под каждую отправку нужно вывести новый div, чтобы по итогу создался список из этих div

Comment: вместо метода `.html(`  использовать `.append(`

Comment: Большое спасибо!